# How to find out the near by restaurants using current location details

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
   I want to find out the near by restaurant details using current location details like latitude,longitude details. Is there any api for that, could any one have idea , please let me know.

Answer :

Hi all , 
I am using http://maps.google.com/?q=restaurents+near+hyderabad&output=kml this url now if it is not working i can follow the urls given by @Karthikeyan.

Comment: google maps api (maps.google.com.....) is deprecated , the new one is google places api which lets you do all location specfic things ,do also go through facebook checkins & foursquare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible in a variety of ways - you can choose

Facebook Checkins - https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant&type=place&center=lat,long&distance=1000

Foursquare API - https://developer.foursquare.com/

Google Places API - Refer their doc before using this -  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 0):

You should look for FourSquare API....I guess that will help you